# Paste a file path onto the beginning of each element of a character list of file names in R

Tags: r, lapply, filepath, paste, sapply

I have a character vector of file names from a folder that I need to transform into individual file paths so each element of the list has the full file path that can then be manipulated using `xmlParse`. The character vector was created using the following example code:

```
files <- list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML")
class(files)
[1] "character"

#output looks like this (there are actually 60+ files - condensed here for example)
> files
 [1] "file1.xml" "file2.xml"
 [3] "file3.xml" "file4.xml"
 [5] "file5.xml" "file6.xml"
```

I need to somehow go through this vector and add the beginning part of the path for each file name so they can be accessed in a loop later on. I've tried various combinations of `lapply`, `paste0`, `sapply` `paste` but keep getting errors in the code.

Here are a couple examples of tries and errors:

```
home.path <- ("C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML")
filepaths <- lapply(files, paste0(home.path))
> filepaths <- lapply(files, paste0(home.path))
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'C:\Users\Documents\XML' of mode 'function' was not found

filepaths <- sapply(files, paste0(home.path, var, sep = ""))
> filepaths <- sapply(files, paste0(home.path, var, sep = ""))
Error in paste0(home.path, var, sep = "") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

If this was working the way I intended, it should return this:

```
>filepaths
[1] "C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML\\file1.xml"
[2] "C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML\\file2.xml"
[3] "C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML\\file3.xml"
...
```

Comment: `list.files()` outputs a vector, why not use `paste0("C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML\\", files)`?

Comment: ...or `paste0(home.path,"\\",files)`

Comment: @AndreWildberg, that worked beautifully! Thank you! Thanks Peter as well, I used the one with the home.path in it since I already was working in further code with that name.

Comment: `list.files()` has an argument to prepend the path so you should be using `list.files(path = "C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML", full.names = TRUE)`.  If you do want to manually construct a file path, use the `file.path()` function instead of `paste()` because `file.path()` will use path separators appropriate to the platform being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `paste0()` directly on the character vector (there's no need for an explicit loop), like so:

```r
filenames <- c("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt")
paste0("prefix/", filenames)
#> [1] "prefix/a.txt" "prefix/b.txt" "prefix/c.txt"
```

R seldom operates on single bits of data; most operations apply to vectors of data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through each file (for editing or combining):

```
for (file in files) {
   print(paste0("C:\\Users\\Documents\\XML\\", file))
}
```